# Loading data R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

My apologies if this has been asked before. 
I am trying to run a basic R shiny app where I take a keyword as text input, search a dataframe on that keyword, and print the result (some item from dataframe)

I have no idea where I am going wrong. When I run the code below nothing happens at all! There is no submit/action button as I am using the default value in textInput.

```
# ui.R

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  h1("Gene Finder",align="left"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, 
           wellPanel(textInput("text", label = h4("Enter Identifier"), value = "BRCA1"))
           ),
    column(6,verbatimTextOutput("genename"))
    )
    )
)
```

Server.R

```
# Server.R
setwd("/shiny-apps/sample-apps/test-1")
load("/shiny-apps/sample-apps/test-1/GenesHg19.RData")

findIdentifier <- function(genename) {
  if(length(grep("ENSG",genename))==0) {
    genename <- as.character(GenesHg19$external_gene_id[which(GenesHg19$external_gene_id==genename)])
  } else {
    genename <- as.character(GenesHg19$ensembl_gene_id[which(GenesHg19$ensembl_gene_id==genename)])
  }
  return(genename)
}

shinyServer(function(input,output) {
  tada <- reactive({ findIdentifier(genename=as.character(input$text)) })
    output$genename <- renderPrint({
        paste("Other known identifiers of",input$text,"are",tada)
    })
})
```

## GenesHg19.RData looks like this

[image]

Comment: first of all you have a typo at last row `gename` should be `genename`

Comment: @warmoverflow Sorry, fixed. Still doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Move `genename <- findIdentifier(genename=input$text)` into the `output$genename`. Perhaps best to provide a minimal example since we can't test anything with the above code.

Comment: This is not really a complete example. For example what is this:  `source('~/.active-rstudio-document')` Are you loading some extra code? And without at least a few lines of the `GenesHg18` data frame it is hard to tell what you are doing.

Comment: If I comment out everything I don't have it comes up fine.

Comment: @MikeWise Thanks for your suggestion. I have removed the source line as I don't know how it got there in the first place (sorry uploaded the code carelessly after a long day). I have added a snapshot of the dataframe I was loading.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example, although can you please explain the purpose of the findIdentifier function?

```
GenesHg19$ensembl_gene_id[which(GenesHg19$ensembl_gene_id==genename)]
```

will always return a 0 length vector or a vector of N x genename, therefore renderPrint will return either "Other known identifiers of genename are " or N times "Other known identifiers of genename are genename"

```
library(shiny)
# setwd("/shiny-apps/sample-apps/test-1") # redundant, shiny server automatically sets the app folder to be working directory
load("GenesHg19.RData")
shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    h1("Gene Finder",align="left"),
    fluidRow(
      column(3, 
             wellPanel(textInput("text", label = h4("Enter Identifier"), value = "BRCA1"))
      ),
      column(6,verbatimTextOutput("genename"))
    )
  )
  ),
  server = shinyServer(function(input,output,session) {
    findIdentifier <- function(genename) {
      if(grepl(x=genename, pattern = 'ENSG')) {
        genename <- as.character(GenesHg19$ensembl_gene_id[which(GenesHg19$ensembl_gene_id==genename)])
      } else {
        genename <- as.character(GenesHg19$external_gene_id[which(GenesHg19$external_gene_id==genename)])
      }
      return(genename)
    }
    tada <- reactive({ findIdentifier(genename=as.character(input$text)) })
    output$genename <- renderPrint({
      paste("Other known identifiers of",input$text,"are",tada()) # reactive variable is function therefore has to be followed by ()
    })
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that shinyServer() by itself is not a reactive function and therefore does not notice the user's input.  In order to get `genename` to update with the user's input, it's necessary to wrap the assignment of the `genename` variable in the call to renderPrint(), because renderPrint() *is* a reactive function and will notice the user's input.

It's worth looking back at the R console after you've launched your Shiny app; the console displays any errors that come up while the Shiny window may fail silently.  For example, you'd have noticed the misspelling mentioned by warmoverflow because R would have said it looked for the variable 'gename' and didn't find it.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps, I was not very clear on use of "Reactive" coding. I have edited the code to use reactive to call findIdentifier(). The problem is still there! What's really bothering me is that there is no error whatsoever on the console. It stays clean as a state, the app keeps running but I do not see anything in the browser at all!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the assignation of `output$genename` in a function, which is then called by reactive()?  So reactive() would call a function, let's call it `displayGeneName`, which would accept the output of `findIdentifier` and which wraps the entire assignation of `output$genename <- renderPrint({ etc })`.  I think your `genename` is getting correctly assigned by reactive(), so there's no error, but then `genename` only exists in the scope of the call to reactive().  A call to a function wrapping renderPrint() from _within_ reactive() would make available all the necessary variables.

Comment: Thanks but I can't get my head around it. Could you please show me how to do that?

Comment: Try `output$genename <- renderPrint({
        paste("Other known identifiers of ",input$text," are ",tada())
    })`; this utilizes tada() as a function, which is what is returned by reactive().